# Receiving audio using bluetooth and performing DSP operations

Tags: python, audio, bluetooth

I wish to create a project on the raspberry in which I can intercept the audio data being received by raspberry pi bluetooth and perform DSP operations on that data (Like Short-time Fourier Transform for a spectrogram, etc). I am preferably looking for Python libraries to achieve this. I have found a lot of information on turning the Pi into an A2DP sink and routing the audio to an output channel for playback using Bluez and Pulseaudio but nothing is really specific on how to capture the audio data being routed to that output.

I have tried to search for similar projects with no luck and finding it surprisingly difficult to find documentation on how the bluetooth is configured to receive audio. I was looking for either documentation, books, articles or similar projects for bluetooth and receiving audio data within a Python script and performing operations on that data if anyone had something available that would be helpful?

Comment: I did a search for "python real time audio processing" and found a number of articles that seem to answer your question so I am not sure what you are looking for. They don't specifically mention Bluetooth audio, but most seem to use pyAudio which allows you to specify the audio device to take the stream from. There are a number of sources about pulseAudio but I often use: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#Set_default_input_source

Comment: Yea its not so much the audio processing part I need help with more understanding how bluetooth interfaces with the Pi and how I can use the input audio data from another source. Thanks for the pulse audio link I think that will be helpful!